# K&R Exercise 1-14 solution

Tags: c

I was working out this exercise and wanted to know if my answer is correct;

> Write a program to print a histogram of the frequencies of different
>   characters in the input.

I have seen a couple of other answers online but they differ quite a lot to mine. Also if there are any problems in the format of my code or any improvements to be made. Any suggestions are welcome. I do understad the question requires a histogram but it's quite easy to build one once I have the data required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int userInput;
    int arrayStuff[92];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 92; ++i){
        arrayStuff[i] = 0;
    }

    while((userInput = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if(userInput >= 30 && userInput <= 122){
            if(userInput != '\n'){
                ++arrayStuff[(userInput-30)];
            }

            if(userInput == '\n'){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Case\t|\tOccurances\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 92; ++i){
        printf("%c\t|\t%d\n", (i+30), arrayStuff[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (userInput == '\n')` can be made `else`, though `userInput` will never be `'\n'` in the loop.

Comment: What is the question? If you want your code reviewed - it might better fit [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I supplied everything in the question, including the actual question and my question..

Comment: since you include both 30 and 122 as valid chars your arrayStuff size should be 93

Comment: blank is ASCII 32 and the last printable ASCII character is 126. The if statement checking for '\n' is superfluous. While loop condition checks for it and the if above it also puts it out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvements I'd make:

- Declare and initialize `int arrayStuff[92] = { 0 };` in one go and get rid of the for loop. This is guaranteed to set **all** elements to 0.
- Don't use the magic number 92 in various places, use `(sizeof arrayStuff/sizeof  arrayStuff[0])` instead to compute the number of elements in arrayStuff.
- Parentheses in (i+30) are redundant
- What happens if the user types the `EOF` character? It looks like it loops forever.
- "Occurances" is not in my dictionary, but occurrence is. Maybe character frequency is a better term?
- arrayStuff? I cannot overemphasize the importance of clear and concise identifier naming. Frequency comes to mind.
- It must be `int main (void)` with a `return 0;`. This is not C++, where an empty parameter list is equivalent to void. This is C, where an empty parameter list means "I'm an old-style K&R parameter list for an unknown but fixed number of arguments."

Answer (score 0):

Jens mentions the "magic number" of 92. A magic number is a number literal in your code. It's recommended that they be avoided since it can be easier to understand the purpose or meaning of the value if it is replaced with a constant variable name, or MACRO name or calculation. I think 30 and 122 would also be considered "magic numbers". This code terminates on input of any non graphic character. Which means it will stop if a tab is entered, and will not count tab characters, which may not be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR 32
#define LAST_GRAPHIC_CHAR 126
#define NUM_GRAPHIC_CHARS (LAST_GRAPHIC_CHAR - FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR + 1)


int main(void)
{

    int userInput;
    int arrayStuff[NUM_GRAPHIC_CHARS] = {0};
    int i;

    printf("enter a string of characters followed by <return>\n");

    userInput = getchar();
    while( userInput >= FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR && userInput <= LAST_GRAPHIC_CHAR )
    {
       ++arrayStuff[(userInput - FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR)];
       userInput = getchar();
    }

    printf("Case\t|\tOccurances\n");

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_GRAPHIC_CHARS; ++i)
    {
        if (  i + FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR == ' ' )
           printf("<spc>\t|\t%d\n",  arrayStuff[i]);
        else
           printf("%c\t|\t%d\n", (i + FIRST_GRAPHIC_CHAR), arrayStuff[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: A `return 0;` might be appropriate for C89.

Comment: @Jens Right. I added return EXIT_SUCCESS since we are talking about magic numbers, but actually don't know if that was around in C89 times.

Comment: Well, according to this post http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2003-11/4816.html it was.

Comment: 0 isn't a magic number, along with 1, i, e and pi. :-)