# How to calculate frequency of characters in a string

Tags: c, arrays, frequency

I am a beginner with C programming so my code is very basic. It is to count the frequency of characters in a string. The program does run but the problem is that it displays each character as many times as it appears in the string. So, when I enter hello, I get "h occurs 1 times, e occurs 1 times, l occurs 2 times, l occurs 2 times, o occurs 1 times". How do i eliminate this and make the count for l appear only once?

```
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
  for(j=0;str[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            if(str[i]==str[j])
                    count[i]++;
        }
}
for(i=0;i<str[i]!='\0';i++)
    printf("%c occurs %d times \n",str[i],count[i]);
```

Comment: What is the definition of `count`? Your code actually calculates something totally random. You do not need the inner loop, but you need an array of counts, where the index is `str[i]` - the ASCII code of the `i`th character in the string.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/Ns9quD)

Comment: @DYZ: Totally random is not accurate — it is defined, but not what is wanted.  I agree that the double loop is unnecessary, but you've over-stated your case.  For a letter that appears twice, the count will be 4; for a letter that appears thrice, the count will be 9; for a letter that appears N times, the count will be N².

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By "totally random" I actually meant "not wanted." But you are right, it does calculate the squares of frequencies!

Comment: The answer to the duplicate I chose calculates the frequency of each character in the string and then suggests a linear scan through the frequency table to find the minimum and maximum frequencies.  You would do the linear scan and print the non-zero frequencies.  There's also [K&R Exercise 1.14 Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382169/kr-exercise-1-14-solution) that is relevant, though the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think building your own function which removes duplicated characters would help you in achieving what you are trying to do. But, there is no standard function that would help you in removing all the duplicates from a string. So try constructing a function to remove all the duplicated/repeated characters from a string and returns the string. Here's what your function would look like:

```
char* remove_duplicated(char* str, int size) {
    int frequency[256] = {0};
    char* new_str = malloc(size);
    int new_size = 0;

    for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(frequency[(unsigned char) str[i]] == 0) {
            frequency[(unsigned char) str[i]]++;
            new_str[new_size] = str[i];
            new_size++;
        }
    }

    new_str[new_size] = '\0';

    return new_str;
}
```

Once you have constructed the above function, send the string in which you want to have the frequencies of characters measured and store the returned string. Something like this:

```
char* new_str = remove_duplicated(str, size);
```

Now in the double `for` loop that you are using, use `new_str` for your outer for loop and also use it for the `for` loop displaying `count`

```
for(i=0; new_str[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    for(j=0; str[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        if(new_str[i] == str[j])
            count[i]++;
    }
 }
 for(i=0; new_str[i]!='\0'; i++)
     printf("%c occurs %d times \n", new_str[i], count[i]);
```

don't forget to free the malloced array in the remove_duplicated function:

```
free(new_str);
```

Here's an online demo: https://ideone.com/KnkwGX

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
int characters[128] = {0};
char string[] = "Hello, World!";
for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    characters[(int)string[i]]++;

for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++) 
    if(characters[i] != 0) 
        printf("%c occurs %d times\n", (char)i, characters[i]);
```

Comment: Since an 8-bit `char` can take 256 values (0..255, or -128..127), it is more usual to use `int frequency[256];` and to make sure you index by values 0..255, cast `str[i]` with `(unsigned char)` before using it to index into the array.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a little difficult to print the count of each letter uniquely with the way you have coded. Try the following way:

```
int frequency[122] = {0}; //ascii value of z is 122.
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    frequency[str[i]]++;
}
for(i=0;i<=122;i++) {
    if(frequency[i] != 0)
        printf("%c occurs %d times\n", str[i], count[i]);
}
```

Comment: Since an 8-bit `char` can take 256 values (0..255, or -128..127), it is more usual to use `int frequency[256];` and to make sure you index by values 0..255, cast `str[i]` with `(unsigned char)` before using it to index into the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Yes. But for this particular problem, the OP is only concerned with alphabets - upper and lower case. So technically, the range of the problem is limited from 65 (A) thru 122 (z). OP can also put a condition check on the value of str[i] to make sure it within this range before processing it.

Comment: The question nowhere mentions 'alphabet'.  Characters such as 'à', 'é', 'ï', 'ø', 'ü', 'ÿ' are characters that can be found in a string — and if the string is encoded in a single-byte code set such as 8859-15, they're single bytes in the unsigned range 128..255, or signed range -128..-1.  There are punctuation characters in the range 123..126, plus DEL at 127; your code won't handle those.  If you checked and ignored values out of range, that would be more or less OK. Programmers making unwarranted assumptions about the input is what leads to viruses and Trojan horses and similar attacks.

Comment: Agreed. But again, OP can always put a condition check on the value of str[i] to make sure it within this range before processing it.